# Attach files to MIME object in gmailr

Tags: r, gmail, gmail-api, mime

I'm struggling to define a proper mime type while trying to attach a file to a letter. I'm testing the function with png-image but eventually I'll need to attach a pdf.

```
library(gmailr)

test_email <- mime(
To = "mymail@yandex.ru",
From = sender_account,
Subject = "this is just a gmailr test",
body = "Can you hear me now?") %>% 
attach_file(file = "health.png", type = "image/png")
send_message(test_email)
```

And get something like this instead of file attached:

`Can you hear me now? --29c4c91341434848f627ac9c696d9ed9--`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well even `mime::guess_type()` wouldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is discussed here:

https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/60

If it is acceptable that the body still contains the --numbers-- string, the following solution worked for me:

```
import(gmailr)

msg <- "This is the message body.\n\n"

email <- mime(
      To = "to@domain.com",
      From = "from@domain.com",
      Subject = "Important subject",
      body = msg)

email <- attach_part(email, msg)
email <- attach_file(email, file = "att1.txt", type = "text/plain")
email <- attach_file(email, file = "att2.txt", type = "text/plain")
email <- attach_file(email, file = "att3.pdf", type = "application/pdf")

send_message(email)
```

Comment: This "almost" works for me: the attachment is there but the body/msg does not show up

Answer (score 1):

Following discussion here: [here](https://github.com/r-lib/gmailr/issues/60) now its fixed.
You need to update gmailr to version 1.0.0 and higher and **update** your code like this

```
pkgload::load_all("~/p/gmailr")
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")
gm_mime() %>%
  gm_from("email@foo.com") %>%
  gm_to("email@bar.com") %>%
  gm_subject("I bought you") %>%
  gm_text_body('Some flowers!') %>%
  gm_attach_file("iris.csv") %>%
  gm_create_draft()
```

Many function names changed by just adding 'gm_' (for example `mime` is `gm_mime` now) but pay attention to authentication, these functions changed much more.